# Deleting Mix of Numbers and Letters

Tags: python, text-files

I have a series of log files containing music that has been played on a music system and at what time.
The tracks on these log files have a unique ID number for example AB008946. How do I delete these ID numbers from the log files and preserve everything else in a python program?

An example of an entry in the file

```
08:04:10 Current Track Playing = AB034214 Skinny Genes - Eliza Doolittle
```

The file is simply a .txt file with a list of these times and tracks

Probably should have mentioned this before but the program I am writing is within a GUI written in tkinter, currently I am filtering the origonal log file down to the list by

```
[line for line in open(fl) if "Current Track Playing" in line]
log = open('log','w').writelines([ line for line in open(fl) if "Current Track Playing" in line])
```

where fl is the origional log file

Sorry I didn't mention this before

Comment: Showing an example of a log file could be helpful

Comment: Example input data and desired output data will help a lot. But the shortanswer is http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub - what the regex is will depend on the data.

Comment: @AdamKG : even better : http://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if they all have that format, you don't even need to do the regex route.

```
>>> s = '08:04:10 Current Track Playing = AB034214 Skinny Genes - Eliza Doolittle'
>>> s_clean = s[:33] + s[42:]
>>> s_clean
'08:04:10 Current Track Playing = Skinny Genes - Eliza Doolittle'
```

For your code example:

```
open('log','w').writelines([
    (line[:33]+line[42:])
    for line in open(fl) if "Current Track Playing" in line])
```

Might need to do some newline munging, not sure.

Comment: Actually, this is a log file... I'd stick to this and *not* use regex. It's the string offset in the line that defines the ID - if there were an artist called (for argument's sake) `AB000000`, no reason that data shouldn't be preserved after the transformation.

Comment: have tried this method but when used to write to the log file all the tracks apart from the last one disappear, ie a file with 220 tracks becomes a file with just the last track on. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sorry bout that, does work now, I just missed you r edit, thatnk you very much good sir

Answer (score 2):

This would be way easier with `sed`:

```
$ cat file
08:04:10 Current Track Playing = AB034214 Skinny Genes - Eliza Doolittle
$ sed -i 's/AB[0-9]*//g' file
$ cat file
08:04:10 Current Track Playing =  Skinny Genes - Eliza Doolittle
```

`s/something/otherthing/g` looks for `something` and replaces it with `otherthing` all around the document (`g`). In this case, it looks for every piece of `AB<numbers>` and deletes them by replacing with an empty string.

#### Update

To be more sure about not deleting improper parts of the string, it can also be used the following:

```
sed 's/= AB[0-9]*/=/g' file
```

([thanks Manuel Gutiérrez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104373/deleting-mix-of-numbers-and-letters/18104568?noredirect=1#comment26503903_18104568)!).

Comment: Except that will mess up `BLINK182` or similar if that was to appear as an artist title.

Comment: @LukasGraf, no. It will just mess on groups whose name is `AB<numbers>`.

Comment: I used Python so many times when all I needed was a line of sed. Maybe OP absolutely needs Python but for quick edits sed is worth it, I guarantee.

Comment: Well, you really think the example ID he gave means all of them start with `AB`? The much more likely case is that they are are IDs in uppercase hexadecimal representation.

Comment: `sed` is definitely very well suited for problems like this - the expression used in this answer is *not*.

Comment: @LukasGraf what about this one `$ sed -i 's/= AB[0-9]* /=/g' file`

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez yes, it always happens to me, sed awk and bash are quite useful tools :) . Also, I was just about to update with this new `sed` expression with more control on the string to changed.

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez much better, since it considers the `= ...`, which makes it very unlikely to match any random sequence of uppercase letters.

Comment: Updated with more control.

Comment: @fedorqui better. Now `"08:04:10 Current Track Playing = AB777777 ABBA - Money, Money, Money"` also works ;-)

Comment: Can you please explain how I would implement this in tkinter?, I am very confused

Comment: @user2595340 oh, I was not aware of it running in tkinter. Now I saw your update on the question. My solution is standalone, you can use it from your prompt and file will be updated. If you have to integrate it within a Python program, my solution is not useful.

Comment: I have tried this method but when used to write to the log file all the tracks apart from the last one disappear, ie a file with 220 tracks becomes a file with just the last track on. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Mmmm strange. Can you indicate me which one of my suggested commands did you use, @user2595340?